# Split up the string with encoded characters

Tags: jquery, regex, solr

I am querying SOLR server and need to handle the facets on the front end, I am having issues with replacing the query strings for sectionLabels. The query formed is as below:

```
var str = 'sectionlabel:%22Using%20Content%22+sectionlabel:%22Build%20Yours%22+sectionlabel:%22Skilled%20Level%3A%20Unleash%20your%20power%22';
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uv3y/5/)**

Problem: I need to get the values from string as below;

**BuildYours** *currenty printing* >> **%22Build%20Yours%22**

So, basically, I need to strip off the encoded character using regex, which I am unable to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about `decodeURIComponent(str)`?

Answer (score 0):

this is one way that you can do it -

```
var arrWords = decodeURIComponent(str).split('+');

for (var i = 0; i < arrWords.length; i++) {
    var label = arrWords[i].replace('sectionlabel:','');
   $('#here').append(label + "<br />");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/8uv3y/6/)

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you

```
var str = 'sectionlabel:%22Using%20Content%22+sectionlabel:%22Build%20Yours%22+sectionlabel:%22Skilled%20Level%3A%20Unleash%20your%20power%22';

 var str_decoded = decodeURIComponent(str);
 var valNew =str_decoded.replace(/\"/g,'').replace(/sectionlabel:/g, '').split('+');

 for (var i = 1; i < valNew.length; i++) {

          $('#here').append(valNew[i] + "<br>");
     }
```

[**DEMO in JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashok1238/5fRME/)